# how to write sin square x in a mod file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

how to write sin square x in a mod file in matlab?

I tried `sin(x).*sin(x) and sin(x).^2`. but it did not work.

It says

> ERROR: character unrecognized by lexer

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is a 'mod' file?

Answer (score -2):

Well after quick search I found that :

sin2theta = sin(theta)*sin(theta)

so try:

```
sin(x)*sin(x)
```

or

```
sin^2(x)= 1/2 - 1/2 cos(2x)
```

You can try using that.